# How to know if an image has been uploaded or not? - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

do you know if is there a method to know if the image has been uploaded?

I mean, i have a Foo_Class, and this class can have an attached image, but its presence is not necessary. Is there a way to know if a particular instance of that class have the image or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you added Paperclip to your model you added paperclip specific rows, mine are

```
cover_file_name
cover_content_type
cover_file_size
cover_updated_at
```

Then I check whether it is nil or not

```
 Foo_Class.cover_file_name.nil?
```

Answer (score 11):

If `foo.image?` returns true, then file uploaded.

Comment: It's now `foo.image.exists?`

Comment: what if you have set `:default_url => 'missing.png'` ? would that be considered as `foo.image.exists?`

Comment: the answer is: no, it will return false

Comment: This technique goes to the server and checks if the file is there. The voted up technique checks if it as been processed and a URL has been generated. Upvoted solution saves lookup (which might be on S3) but it does not check if the file actually exists on the image server (which you may or may not want to check.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the proper solution is to use the `file?` method.

foo.image.file?

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Attachment#file%3F-instance_method

using exists? will do a request to the server to check if the file is there, which can be quite slow, especially if it's on a different server or on S3.

using foo.image_file_name.nil? is probably the same as file? under the covers, but ou don't want to dependant on the implementation of paperclip, which could someday change.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in my **model**

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:logo => "230x50>", :card_image => "180x50>"}
```

You can check if the image is uploaded for a user i.e @user

```
<%= @user.avatar.exists? %>
```

This will return boolean value.

Comment: If your file is on S3, this will trigger a request to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to check the presence of attachment(image) for the 1st row in Foo model:

```
image_present = Foo.first.image?
```

This returns true if the attachment is present.