# Rails 4 x paperclip: test if a file has been uploaded with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip

In my Rails 4 app, I allow users to upload images with the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="post_image">IMAGE</label><br>
  <input type="file" name="post[image]" id="post_image">
</div>
```

I need to display a custom message, depending on whether a user has uploaded an image yet or not.

For instance, when he first loads the page, I want to display "You have not uploaded an image yet." but then, when he uploads an image, I want to display "You have uploaded an image.".

I know how to test if a record has an attachment with Ruby — as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593829/how-to-know-if-an-image-has-been-uploaded-or-not-paperclip) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397627/paperclip-test-if-images-have-been-uploaded) — but all of this should happen without reloading the page, so I am looking for a JavaScript solution.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery File Upload gem](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) to upload image without redirect and based on this you can do something like

```
$('.image-container').length != 0 // To check if image exists
```

Then you can show your notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already implemented file upload with `paperclip` throughout the app and would like to avoid switching to another gem for that matter.

Comment: @ThibaudClement I'm not sure but afaik you can't do that with `paperclip`

Comment: Thanks. I think there may be a way to achieve that through XHR calls, but not sure.